# Speech recognition no reset after restarting Choregraphe application

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

When starting my Choregraphe application it has two flows, one is for the dialogs that goes to greetings and the other is to restart the application from the beginning if we press the foot with the bumper.

[image]

Inside the greetings we have this:

[image: Image2]

My problem is that when I enter this flow and go to speech recognition number 2 (highlighted in blue), 3, 4 or any other than the first one, and I press the bumper to restart, when I re-enter the flow from the beginning and try to run speech recognition number 1, it keeps running the last speech recognition that was left, and not the first one.
In other words, speech recognition 2 is still running instead of 1.

I've tried unsubscribed, subscribed, pause and all the speech recognition stuff with python scripts, but it hasn't worked at all.

Comment: Someone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

When you press the bumper you are re-triggering the greetings and the subsequent flow, but you do not stop the ongoing flow first.

To do so, I would:

- connect the bumper output to the stop of the GREETING box and to the first input of a "Wait for signal"
- connect the GREETING output to the other input of the "Wait for signal"
- connect the output of the "Wait for signal" to the beginning of the the restart flow (the say and the subsequent restart of the GREETING box)